# My django form isn't catching ValidationErrors

Tags: python, django, forms, validation

So I have a custom form field that basically checks my DB to see if a given value (a voucher code) is valid. I have in **forms.py**

```
class VoucherField(CharField):
    def to_python(self, value):
        if not value:
            return ""
        return value

    def validate(self, value):
        super(CharField, self).validate(value)

        vouchers = Vouchers.objects[0]
        if not value in vouchers.valid:
            raise ValidationError('This voucher is invalid or has been used already.')


class PurchaseForm(Form):
    voucher = VoucherField(required=True)    
    ...
```

and in views.py

```
def orderHandler(request):
    form = PurchaseForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        # Processes
    else:
        # Return errors
```

The problem is the form.is_valid() line keeps causing Django to throw a **ValidationError** instead of catching it and saving the message to form.errors. I'm not sure why this is happening

Comment: Anytime you want help debugging you should include the full stack trace of the error. Also, it should be `super(VoucherField, self)`.

Comment: Is that inheriting from forms.CharField or models.CharField? Usually you would define `clean` on a form field, not `validate`.